# GLYPHICONS in Bootstrap 2.3.2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

How can I use GLYPHICONS in Bootstrap 2.3.2? I've downloaded the Glyphicons ZIP. But I have no idea how to install it. Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation page shows you how:
http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#icons

I originally did not want to answer this question but post a comment instead, but I don't have enough reputation. If this is not exactly what you were after, please elaborate your circumstance.

## UPDATE

Here is a working example with the 'search' icon in a button:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        body {
            margin-top: 60px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <button class="btn btn-large" type="button"><i class="icon-search"></i> Search</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the corresponding result:

[image: Screenshot of code]

Comment: Thanks. But I already know this. What I'm asking for is HOW to make those icons work. I have to connect GLYPHICONS to my HTML page. But I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Did you check the 'How to use' section which comes right after?

Comment: I did checked it. It's not working - the code that you gave.

Comment: How did you place your files and which bootstrap package did you download? I downloaded the compiled version from [here](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/bootstrap.zip). Just extract it to a folder and place your html file in the root.

Comment: I didn't downloaded this version now. I already had it downloaded from a long time ago.

Comment: Those big images were the problem? I didn't had them from the beginning. It works now. Thanks!